# Email Message save to Local Folder through EWS

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I am using this method to save email message to local drive and it's worked fine if there is an attachment with email.

```
          _emailMessage.Load(new PropertySet(ItemSchema.MimeContent)); 
           MimeContent mc = _emailMessage.MimeContent;
           var path = Path.Combine(DirFullPath, emailMsgName);            
           FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);        
           fs.Write(mc.Content, 0, mc.Content.Length);                
           fs.Close();
```

If there is no attachment it throws an exception and not able to save emailmessage to the folder. Here is the exception "This operation can't be performed because this service object doesn't have an Id."

Please let me know how to deal with this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us more information? The issue probably has nothing to do with the presence of an attachment. Can you show me all of the actions taken on _emailMessage?

Comment: Before save, I am sending email message to recipient through this method.  _emailMessage.SendAndSaveCopy(WellKnownFolderName.SentItems); This method sends the email and saves the email in sender's sent items folder. There is no problem but it didn't save to folder on local drive. If there is any attachment with email everything works fine. It's better if you provide any example to save the email when there is no attachment. I am using Exchange2007_SP1 for exchange service.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps some code path doesn't use a EmailMessage.Save or EmailMessage.Bind before you use EmailMessage.Load.